# Determine if .NET ListView control is editing

Tags: c#, listview

I'm using a windows forms ListView in a C# application and I capture the KeyDown event on it to allow deleting a row using the Delete key.  The TreeView class has the TreeNode.IsEditing property if I ever needed it but I couldn't find one in the ListView class.  If the user is editing the label of a ListViewItem, I want the Delete key to do the default behavior instead of deleting the item.  Is there any built in property I can use?  Or do I need to trap both the Before and AfterLabelEdit events?

Edit:
Sorry, I had a context menu set with the keyboard shortcut set to the Delete key.  This is the event getting called and not the KeyDown event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are subscribed to **KeyDown** event on **ListView**, when you are editing the label of an item the **KeyDown** event is not hit.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I had a context menu shortcut key which was getting called.  Is there a way to make that work elegantly?

Comment: take a look at this question, it should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358973/delete-in-edit-menu